# How to add tapGesture to UIView with tapHandler in ViewController?

Tags: swift

I want to init my UIView with tapGestureRecognizer and i want to my ViewController tapHandler func called every time i tap UIView. I think it should look like this:

**Initialising UIVIew**

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
{
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   let tab = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: ViewController, action:
   #selector(ViewController.tapHandler(view: self))) }
   self.addGestureRecognizer(tab)
}
```

But it does not work. How can i set target to ViewController and action to tapHandler in ViewControler?

Comment: You have to pass a reference to an existing object instance to the `target` parameter.

Comment: Does your `UIView` exist on storyboard or you are initialising it with code ?